# Среднее число из массива

Tags: javascript

Решил раскрыть стрелки для лучшего понимания кода внизу.

Где-то я допустил ошибку.

Но не могу понять, где именно.

Оригинал кода:

```js
function getAverageAge(users) {
  return users.reduce((prev, user) => prev + user.age, 0) / users.length;
}

let vasya = { name: "Вася", age: 25 };
let petya = { name: "Петя", age: 30 };
let masha = { name: "Маша", age: 29 };

let arr = [ vasya, petya, masha ];

alert( getAverageAge(arr) ); // 28
```

С раскрытой функцией(Тут ошибка)

```js
function getAverageAge(users) {
  return users.reduce(function(prev, user){
  return prev + user.age, 0;      
  }) 
}

let vasya = { name: "Вася", age: 25 };
let petya = { name: "Петя", age: 30 };
let masha = { name: "Маша", age: 29 };

let arr = [ vasya, petya, masha ];

alert( getAverageAge(arr) ); // 28
```

Comment: Зачем так сложно. Среднее (оно же математическое ожидание расчитывается просто)...
Сумма всех возрастов / кол-во народа.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`, 0` относился не к той функции. Надо было к `reduce` как второй параметр сделать, а вы пытались вернуть значения через запятую, в числе которых был ноль

```js
function getAverageAge(users) {
  return users.reduce(function(prev, user){
      return prev + user.age;      
  }, 0)  / users.length;
}

let vasya = { name: "Вася", age: 25 };
let petya = { name: "Петя", age: 30 };
let masha = { name: "Маша", age: 29 };

let arr = [ vasya, petya, masha ];

alert( getAverageAge(arr) ); // 28
```

---

Было:

```
return users.reduce(function(prev, user){return prev + user.age, 0;})
```

Стало:

```
return users.reduce(function(prev, user){return prev + user.age;}, 0)
```

Comment: А тут люди внизу говорят, что надо разделить на кол-во элементов в массиве.  Я так и сделал, но у меня вышло число 9.3.
 return prev + user.age / users.length. Так и должно быть?

Comment: @Человек Так ведь это деление **уже** прописано в функции. Если оно там есть - то больше делить нигде ничего не надо. Если это убрать из функции, то тогда  **вне** её надо будет разделить

Comment: И вправду, по невнимательности не заметил. Благодарю вас.

Comment: Извините за беспокойство, хотел бы задать еще один вопрос.
В вашем коде:    return prev + user.age; } , после age обязательно ставить точку с запятой? Если ее не поставить это не будет считаться ошибкой?

Comment: По идее ошибкой не будет. Но я рекомендую её ставить всегда. Потому что один раз не поставив можно наткнуться на большие неприятности.  И как минимум это визуально показывает, что инструкция закончилась, точно так же, как отделение фигурным скобками функций и конструкций

Answer (score 2):

у вас ошибка была со скобками в методе `reduce`

этот метод принимает 2 параметра, первый параметр - функция, вызывая для каждого элемента, второй параметр - начальное значение (если он не указан, то в качестве начального значения будет взять первый элемент массива)

ну и раз вы считаете среднее - то уж извольте сумму полученную разделить на кол-во элементов в массиве :)

```js
function getAverageAge(users) {
    return users.reduce(
        function(prev, user){
            return prev + user.age;
        }, 
        0); 
}

let vasya = { name: "Вася", age: 25 };
let petya = { name: "Петя", age: 30 };
let masha = { name: "Маша", age: 29 };

let arr = [ vasya, petya, masha ];

alert( getAverageAge(arr) / arr.length ); // 28
```

по хорошему можно сделать такой код:

```js
function getAverageAge(users) {
    return users.reduce(
        function(prev, user){
            return prev + user.age;
        }, 
        0) / users.length; 
}

let vasya = { name: "Вася", age: 25 };
let petya = { name: "Петя", age: 30 };
let masha = { name: "Маша", age: 29 };

let arr = [ vasya, petya, masha ];

alert(getAverageAge(arr)); // 28
```

Comment: Попробовал разделить и получилось 9.3:
return prev + user.age / users.length;
По-моему это не правильно.

Comment: @Человек, делить надо ОКОНЧАТЕЛЬНЫЙ результат, а не ПРОМЕЖУТОЧНЫЙ - я же код привел - в нем 28 получается, можно и промежуточный, но тогда уж удалите деление в окончательном результате, который я сделал `getAverageAge(arr) / arr.length ); `

Comment: Но без деления результат получается тот же. В чем подвох?

Comment: @Человек, не понял, что значит тот же? посмотрите, я второй код привел, который ваш подход учитывает

Comment: Спасибо, я не заметил деление. Теперь все стало ясно.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const getAverageAgeOpen = (u)=>{
    const als = (a)=>a.reduce((c, b)=>c + b.age, 0);
    return (als(u) / u.length) | 0;
};

const getAverageAge = (u)=>(u.reduce((c, b)=>c + b.age, 0) / u.length) | 0;

const arr = [{age: 25}, {age: 30}, {age: 29}];
console.log(getAverageAgeOpen(arr));
console.log(getAverageAge(arr));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
var humans = {
    vasya : {name: "Вася", age: 25},
    petya : {name: "Петя", age: 30},
    masha : {name: "Маша", age: 29}
};
var result = 0;
for(var i in humans) {
    var obj = humans[i];
    result += obj.age;
}

result = result/Object.keys(humans).length;
</script>
```

Округление результата уже по потребностям.